# Why I can't use my Pyparsing in my Python Idle but i can use that in my Anaconda/Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I already displaying my plot in anaconda Jupyter, but want to display that plot in my shell.

Problem appear when the code to show the plot is executed in my Shell/IDE.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

> The output from my Shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WIN 10/Desktop/#2019GantiSarjana/Tulis Skripsi/TampilDataParang.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\WIN 10\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\WIN 10\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Users\WIN 10\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you see this error in your command line tool e.g. Windows cmd or
>   Linux terminal. Run the command as below

```
pip install pyparsing
```

> If you see this error in your IDE (Integrated Development Environment)
>   GUI tool

1. Navigate to your current Project Settings or Configuration either from File or Right clicking Project
2. Go to Project Interpreter being used
3. Under this there should be list of packages installed
4. Find the button to add / install a new package, search or select 'pyparsing' and install

Then it should work in the IDE.

**Jupyter will always have most of the packages pre-installed**

Good Luck!